# How to format a Java string with leading zero?

Tags: java, string, formatting, format

Here is the String, for example:

```
"Apple"
```

and I would like to add zero to fill in 8 chars:

```
"000Apple"
```

How can I do so?

Answer (score 331, accepted):

In case you have to do it without the help of a library:

```
("00000000" + "Apple").substring("Apple".length())
```

(Works, as long as your String isn't longer than 8 chars.)

Comment: That's pretty clever -- but it took me about 30 seconds to "get it". I think a more readable solution would be better.

Comment: This is an -excellent- solution when you are embedding software on something without much space and the extra libraries just aren't an option. Thanks!!

Comment: This version is crazy fast! I love it.

Comment: This is fast & works for whatever length.

    public static String prefixZeros(String value, int len) {
        char[] t = new char[len];
        int l = value.length();
        int k = len-l;
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++) { t[i]='0'; }
        value.getChars(0, l, t, k);
        return new String(t);
    }

Yes, there is no formatting here :( see code below.

Comment: @Mathu honestly that is not difficult to understand.  Two strings are concatenated (joined together) and the first 5 characters are extracted from it.  No magic.  Not very sensible in this case (for fixed string Apple) but easy to understand.  `("0000" + theString).substring(theString.length())` is more realistic.  This pads `theString` with leading zeros.  Sorry couldn't resist adding this comment :)

Comment: @Dici It does "work" for a larger size, it just truncates your string to 8 characters .... So it depends on your expected behavior for longer-than-8-character strings (which wasn't specified by the OP)

Comment: This solution has a short syntax but it's not "crazy fast". If you're lucky the compiler will optimize it but essentially the real "fast" way to do this is using a `StringBuilder`, and it takes a loop to fill it. If the requirement is really to only truncate 8-characters strings that's ok, although that's a very narrow use-case, but this solution can never be called fast. It is just short.

Comment: Though it works, I wouldn't recommend using this way. It's not as clean as using String.format, which essentially is what you are trying to do: give a number a String format. By using this you need to read the statement twice to find out what it is doing.

Comment: @AmyB This is extremely readable.

Comment: `StringUtils.right(("00000000" + "Apple"),8)`

Answer (score 402):

```
public class LeadingZerosExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int number = 1500;

       // String format below will add leading zeros (the %0 syntax) 
       // to the number above. 
       // The length of the formatted string will be 7 characters.

       String formatted = String.format("%07d", number);

       System.out.println("Number with leading zeros: " + formatted);
    }
}
```

Comment: but I would like to adding leading zero before a string instead of an int.

Comment: You can use StringUtils or DecimalFormat for Java 1.4 and below. Check here http://javadevnotes.com/java-integer-to-string-with-leading-zeros

Comment: @Variag  use `%07s`  instead of `%07d`, you will get a `FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException`. you can try it.

Comment: Weird! `int number = "Apple";` didn't work! How odd? 

Answer (score 172):

```
 StringUtils.leftPad(yourString, 8, '0');
```

This is from [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/). [See javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#leftPad-java.lang.String-int-char-)

Comment: Why not use commons-lang? It has a loot of useful extras.

Comment: Even if you are not able to use commons-lang, you can easily copy the source from StringUtils to make your own function.  That would be a much better general solution than the selected answer. http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java.html

Comment: what if that would be the only method the library is used for? Perhaps the added library is even many times bigger than the app it is used in. I can imagine quite some reasons *not* to add a commons library in an application. Don't get me wrong: I agree, it contains very useful stuff, but I understand the reluctance to stuff an app full of external JARs if the benefit is not needing to write just one (or a couple) of methods.

Comment: @kaliatech: yes, a much better GENERAL solution, but if he don't want to use the library probably a focused (short) solution is more appropriate.

Comment: To answer the _"Why not use commons-lang? It has a loot of useful extras."_ question with a concrete example. Xiaomi ships an outdated version of commons-lang on its Android devices. Including a newer version in your app leads to classloader conflicts, so commons-lang can no longer be used in any Android project.

Comment: @Nachi even if outdated StringUtils.leftPad should exist

Comment: Updated Javadoc API links: [current stable release 3.9](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#leftPad-java.lang.String-int-char-), [legacy release 2.6](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#leftPad(java.lang.String,%20int,%20char))

Comment: one would have to include apache commons lang jar into your class path. Why ? when you already have String.Format. See @Alex-Rashkov answer below.

Answer (score 42):

This is what he was really asking for I believe:

```
String.format("%0"+ (8 - "Apple".length() )+"d%s",0 ,"Apple");
```

output:

```
000Apple
```

Comment: Doesn't work for the general case; if you substitute "Apple" with a string of length 8 characters (which is possible in OP's case) this throws a `DuplicateFormatFlagsException` (because of the `00` in the format string). If you substitute a string longer than 8 characters, this throws an `IllegalFormatFlagsException` (because of the negative number).

Comment: You are right, but what about this then : `String.format("%0"+ (9 - "Apple".length() )+"d%s",0 ,"Apple").substring(0,8); `. Now you wont have  this exception.

Comment: Just wanna add `String.format("%0"+ (9 - "Apple".length() )+"d%s",0 ,"Apple").substring(0,8);` is WRONG, it should be `String.format("%0"+ (9 - "Apple".length() )+"d%s",0 ,"Apple").substring(1,9); `.

Comment: @user4231709 Great solution! +1

Answer (score 31):

You can use the String.format method as used in another answer to generate a string of 0's,

```
String.format("%0"+length+"d",0)
```

This can be applied to your problem by dynamically adjusting the number of leading 0's in a format string:

```
public String leadingZeros(String s, int length) {
     if (s.length() >= length) return s;
     else return String.format("%0" + (length-s.length()) + "d%s", 0, s);
}
```

It's still a messy solution, but has the advantage that you can specify the total length of the resulting string using an integer argument.

Answer (score 16):

You can use this:

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.leftPad("Apple", 8, "0")
```

Comment: By far the best answer.  Apache commons StringUtils is a simple yet extremely helpful library.

Comment: This saved a lot of time and it's neat and clean as well.

Answer (score 16):

Using Guava's [`Strings`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#padStart(java.lang.String,int,char)) utility class:

```
Strings.padStart("Apple", 8, '0');
```

Answer (score 13):

I've been in a similar situation and I used this; It is quite concise and you don't have to deal with length or another library.

```
String str = String.format("%8s","Apple");
str = str.replace(' ','0');
```

Simple and neat. String format returns `"   Apple"` so after replacing space with zeros, it gives the desired result.

Comment: Then you may want to split the string first, apply the operation above to the first split value, than concatenate the rest of the split values.

Comment: if "Apple" had spaces in it, the spaces would be replaced with 0s.

Comment: this can be shortened to `String str = String.format("%8s","Apple").replace(' ', '0');`

Answer (score 6):

```
String input = "Apple";
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(input);

while (buf.length() < 8) {
  buf.insert(0, '0');
}

String output = buf.toString();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [Apache Commons StringUtils.leftPad](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#leftPad-java.lang.String-int-) (or look at the code to make your own function).

- [JavaDoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#leftPad-java.lang.String-int-)
- [Source](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/76668705396365c71722c39d45a3b263713f108f/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java#L5246)

Copied Source:

```java
    /**
     * Left pad a String with a specified String.
     *
     * <p>Pad to a size of {@code size}.</p>
     *
     * <pre>
     * StringUtils.leftPad(null, *, *)      = null
     * StringUtils.leftPad("", 3, "z")      = "zzz"
     * StringUtils.leftPad("bat", 3, "yz")  = "bat"
     * StringUtils.leftPad("bat", 5, "yz")  = "yzbat"
     * StringUtils.leftPad("bat", 8, "yz")  = "yzyzybat"
     * StringUtils.leftPad("bat", 1, "yz")  = "bat"
     * StringUtils.leftPad("bat", -1, "yz") = "bat"
     * StringUtils.leftPad("bat", 5, null)  = "  bat"
     * StringUtils.leftPad("bat", 5, "")    = "  bat"
     * </pre>
     *
     * @param str  the String to pad out, may be null
     * @param size  the size to pad to
     * @param padStr  the String to pad with, null or empty treated as single space
     * @return left padded String or original String if no padding is necessary,
     *  {@code null} if null String input
     */
    public static String leftPad(final String str, final int size, String padStr) {
        if (str == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (isEmpty(padStr)) {
            padStr = SPACE;
        }
        final int padLen = padStr.length();
        final int strLen = str.length();
        final int pads = size - strLen;
        if (pads <= 0) {
            return str; // returns original String when possible
        }
        if (padLen == 1 && pads <= PAD_LIMIT) {
            return leftPad(str, size, padStr.charAt(0));
        }

        if (pads == padLen) {
            return padStr.concat(str);
        }
        if (pads < padLen) {
            return padStr.substring(0, pads).concat(str);
        }
        final char[] padding = new char[pads];
        final char[] padChars = padStr.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < pads; i++) {
            padding[i] = padChars[i % padLen];
        }
        return new String(padding).concat(str);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
String.format("%08d", "Apple");
```

It seems to be the simplest method and there is no need of any external library.

Comment: String.format("%08d", anInteger);  // this worked for me. String version throws exception

Comment: This won't run.

Comment: Agree with @Heiner, formatting String with number format will fail.

Comment: I am getting errors as well.

Answer (score 2):

In Java:

```
String zeroes="00000000";
String apple="apple";

String result=zeroes.substring(apple.length(),zeroes.length())+apple;
```

In Scala:

```
"Apple".foldLeft("00000000"){(ac,e)=>ac.tail+e}
```

You can also explore a way in Java 8 to do it using streams and reduce (similar to the way I did it with Scala). It's a bit different to all the other solutions and I particularly like it a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Solution with method String::repeat (Java 11)

```
String str = "Apple";
String formatted = "0".repeat(8 - str.length()) + str;
```

If needed change 8 to another number or parameterize it

Answer (score 2):

I like the solution from [Pad a String with Zeros](https://www.baeldung.com/java-pad-string)

```
String.format("%1$" + length + "s", inputString).replace(' ', '0');
```

with length = "8" and inputString = "Apple"

Answer (score 1):

```
public class PaddingLeft {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "Apple";
        String result = "00000000" + input;
        int length = result.length();
        result = result.substring(length - 8, length);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have to take care of edgecase. This is a generic method.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(padCharacter("0",8,"hello"));
    }
    public static String padCharacter(String c, int num, String str){
        for(int i=0;i<=num-str.length()+1;i++){str = c+str;}
        return str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String stringForTest = "Apple";
    int requiredLengthAfterPadding = 8;
    int inputStringLengh = stringForTest.length();
    int diff = requiredLengthAfterPadding - inputStringLengh;
    if (inputStringLengh < requiredLengthAfterPadding)
    {
        stringForTest = new String(new char[diff]).replace("\0", "0")+ stringForTest;
    }
    System.out.println(stringForTest);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String lpad(String str, int requiredLength, char padChar) {
    if (str.length() > requiredLength) {
        return str;
    } else {
        return new String(new char[requiredLength - str.length()]).replace('\0', padChar) + str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Did anyone tried this pure Java solution (without SpringUtils):

```
//decimal to hex string 1=> 01, 10=>0A,..
String.format("%1$2s", Integer.toString(1,16) ).replace(" ","0");
//reply to original question, string with leading zeros. 
//first generates a 10 char long string with leading spaces, and then spaces are
//replaced by a zero string. 
String.format("%1$10s", "mystring" ).replace(" ","0");
```

Unfortunately this solution works only if you do not have blank spaces in a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is fast & works for whatever length.

```
public static String prefixZeros(String value, int len) {
    char[] t = new char[len];
    int l = value.length();
    int k = len-l;
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++) { t[i]='0'; }
    value.getChars(0, l, t, k);
    return new String(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be faster then [Chris Lercher answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4051991/4891683) when most of in String have exacly 8 char

```
int length = in.length();
return length == 8 ? in : ("00000000" + in).substring(length);
```

in my case on my machine 1/8 faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple API-less "readable script" version I use for pre-padding a string. (Simple, Readable, and Adjustable).

```
while(str.length() < desired_length)
  str = '0'+str;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the program in pure Java you can follow the below method or there are many String Utils to help you better with more advanced features.

Using a simple static method you can achieve this as below.

```
public static String addLeadingText(int length, String pad, String value) {
    String text = value;
    for (int x = 0; x < length - value.length(); x++) text = pad + text;
    return text;
}
```

You can use the above method `addLeadingText(length, padding text, your text)`

```
addLeadingText(8, "0", "Apple");
```

The output would be **000Apple**

Answer (score -3):

It isn't pretty, but it works. If you have access apache commons i would suggest that use that

```
if (val.length() < 8) {
  for (int i = 0; i < val - 8; i++) {
    val = "0" + val;
  }
}
```

Comment: The -1 is probably because this is a not so good example: you're using "magic numbers" and are concatenating Strings, something that should be replaced by using a StringBuilder or StringBuffer.

Comment: This is not a good answer due to `val - 8` isn't correct logic for the Java and will cause compile error