# Reading excel using POI HSSFCell with leading zeros

Tags: java, excel, poi-hssf

I am trying to read an excel file using Java POI HSSF. Everything was working fine, except that when the value is 001001 the HSSFCell will return 1001.0

Is there any way I can use HSSFCell to get the value 001001 ?

I am not supposed to do any modification to the excel file.

Thank in advance for any help and suggestion.

**Edit**

I have been using the following code:

cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
cell.toString();

I also ran a debug mode and checked on the cell value the moment the HSSF grabs it. It truncate the leading zeros and converted it to double therefore I do not see a way to retrieve the truncated zeros. There is a link that stated it could be a bug from HSSF:
http://osdir.com/ml/jakarta.poi.user/2003-02/msg00007.html

By the way, I solved it by hard coded it. The number of digits are know in advanced. The link for the code that I used: [How to format a Java string with leading zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051887/how-to-format-a-java-string-with-leading-zero)

Comment: Try reading it as a string

Comment: I have tried the cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING); line previously. It helps to save the need of differentiating whether is a numeric value or string value. I also just tried the other 2 lines of code, I still get 1001.

Comment: I ran on debug mode previously. From the HssfCell value, I can see that the value is 1001.0 then how does it know to get back the 2 leading zero if it is already truncated ?

Comment: That question is to distinguish the data value of 2.0 and 2. To read the it in string format. Therefore the code: cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) will work. For my case is that I would to keep the leading zeros: 001001, but I keep getting 1001 or 1001.0

Comment: I have used DataFormatter df=new DataFormatter();  for(int i=3;i<=lastRowNum;i++)
  {
   hrow = sheet.getRow(i);
   hcell = hrow.getCell(2);
   cellVal1=df.formatCellValue(hcell);
   System.out.println(cellVal1);
  }   and it worked perfectly.  cellVal1 is a String object. rest all understood i reckon.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try reading it as a string instead of Numeric,

```
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
```

Changing the cell type usually will not modify the contents of the cell.
it can be retrieved with either of the following approaches:

```
cell.getStringCellValue();

cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
```