# Adding 0's to string/int variable

Tags: java, eclipse, string

So I have been working on a naming convention which add 0's before a string. I'm trying to do this the short handed way before breaking everything into if statements. Here I print 0's before an int giving me an answer of 00005.

```
String test = null;
int n = 5;
test = String.format("%05d%n", n);  
System.out.println(test);
```

Now what I would like to do is do this to a String. So for example if String n = "5"; it would give me an answer of  00005 and if String n = "20"; it would be 00020. I do not wish to use the integer method to change the string to and int, and back into a string. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
("00000" + numberAsString).substring(numberAsString.length())
```

This will only work if you have 5 or less digit numbers.

[Ideone link to check code](https://ideone.com/QaoxmO)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4051991/1066828)

To be honest, I also think 4 times how this code works, but after understanding I posted as this is something out of the box.

Comment: `Math.min(numberAsString.length(),5)`?  Then you could get rid of the restriction.

Comment: @ajb : Right... But I wrote note just to inform OP as he is looking for 5 digit only... If OP want to increase for more width, OP will add additional 0's in the code itself...

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if it's the best way, but that's what I use.

```
public static String pad (String input, char with, int desiredLength)
{
    if (input.length() >= desiredLength) {
        return input;
    }
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder (desiredLength);
    for (int i = input.length (); i < desiredLength; i++) {
        output.append (with);
    }
    output.append (input);

    return output.toString();
}
```

Usage (assuming the static method is in a class called Utils) :

```
System.out.println (Utils.pad(myString,'0',10));
```

EDIT : generalized to any input String, character to pad with, and desired output length.

Comment: + you should create your own class and call it something meaningful so you don't have to repeat yourself everywhere

Comment: I'd add a simple check at the beginning: `if (input.length() >= desiredLength) return input;`.

Comment: @MikeStrobel agreed, that would save the allocation of the StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `n` is a `String` that represents a number, or more generally that `n` doesn't have any space characters:

```
String.format("%5s",n).replace(" ","0");
```

Comment: That only works if the original String has no spaces, which is true if the String represents a number, but doesn't work for arbitrary Strings.

Comment: @Eran Right, I assumed it represented a number.  I can't think of a case where you'd want to do this otherwise.

Comment: You could fix it by using n.trim() in the format statement ;) ... It's possible that the String value may come from at her source, file, web service or been sub-stringed in some way, so it's nice to "ensure" an accurate value ;)