# How to retain trailing zeroes when converting BigDecimal to String

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have to convert a `BigDecimal` value, e.g. `2.1200`, coming from the database to a string. When I use the `toString()` or `toPlainString()` of `BigDecimal`, it just prints the value `2.12` but not the trailing zeroes.

How do I convert the `BigDecimal` to string without losing the trailing zeroes?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051887/how-to-format-a-java-string-with-leading-zero

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to nicely format floating numbers to String without unnecessary decimal 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0)

Answer (score 6):

try this..

```
MathContext mc = new MathContext(6); // 6 precision
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(2.12000, mc);
System.out.println(bigDecimal.toPlainString());//2.12000
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question, when he's got a BigDecimal already in hand . . .

Comment: yes it was my mistake now look at my answer @GingerHead btw thanks!!

Comment: This assumes that 6 is the required precision always.

Comment: It didnt work for me.. The below code printing "100.25"
`MathContext mc = new MathContext(6);
        BigDecimal i = new BigDecimal(100.250, mc);
        System.out.println(i.toPlainString());` And also what if I have to convert the BigDecimal object which returned from an method to String ? Here you hardcoaded the value right?

Comment: Yes @PadmanabhanVijendran the precision is hardcoded. I did not get you about the conversion. Please elaborate it or post a new question with what you tried, what you achieved and where you are facing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

To convert a `BigDecimal` to a `String` with a particular pattern you need to use a `DecimalFormat`.

```
BigDecimal value = .... ;
String pattern = "#0.0000"; // If you like 4 zeros
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
String output = myFormatter.format(value);
System.out.println(value + " " + pattern + " " + output);
```

To check the possible values of pattern see here [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

Comment: Can you specify what a `value` is ?

Comment: value is your BigDecimal. I edited the answer to show it

Comment: I know exactly what it is . . .

Answer (score 0):

```
double value = 1.25;
// To convet double to bigdecimal    
BigDecimal bigDecimalValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(value);   
//set 4 trailing value
BigDecimal tempValue = bigDecimalValue.setScale(4, RoundingMode.CEILING);
System.out.println(tempValue.toPlainString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code .

```
    BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("1.200");
    System.out.println(d);
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(d));
```

Output is as below :
`1.200
 1.200`

Answer (score -3):

In a practical way, just don't use BigDecimal, instead use toString() of Double class.