# Java String Format: "%0" and "d%s"

Tags: java, string, formatting, format

I would like to know what is the meaning of `"%0"` and `"d%s"` in java when formatting a `string`.

```
String.format("%0"+ (8 - "Apple".length() )+"d%s",0 ,"Apple");
```

Output:

```
000Apple
```

I was searching for a way to format a string with leading zeros, and that code does the work, but I don't know why it works.

Found that line of code here:
[How to format a Java string with leading zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051887/how-to-format-a-java-string-with-leading-zero)

Comment: you might have problems for strings larger than 8 chars

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`%d` means number. `%0nd` means zero-padded number with a length.

You build `n` by subtraction in your example.

`%s` is a string.

Your format string ends up being this:

```
"%03d%s", 0, "Apple"
```

So you print a zero-padded 0 that's three digits long, and the string `"Apple"`.