# Check Protection Format

Tags: java, currency

I'm trying to write an application that inputs a dollar amount to be printed on a check, I'm having trouble figuring out how to print out the number in a check protected with leading **** asterisks.

Here's the code I have so far

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import  java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
public class CheckProtection
{
    private static double maxAmount = 1000;
    public static void main (String args [])
    {

        //System.out.printf(checkFormatter.format(check));
        //DecimalFormat checker = new DecimalFormat("******.**");
        //System.out.println(checker);
        boolean validEntry = false;
        while (validEntry == false)
        {
            Scanner userEntry = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter The check amount under a $1000.00 and greater that 0.");
            if (userEntry.hasNextDouble() == true)
            {
                double check = userEntry.nextDouble();
                if (check > 0)
                {
                    if(check < maxAmount)
                    {
                        validEntry = true;

                        NumberFormat checkFormatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
                        checkFormatter.format(check);
                        System.out.printf("%5s",+ check);
                    }
                }
            }
        }








    }
```

Comment: We are going to need a little more than a code dump. What are some inputs/expected outputs/actual outputs?

Comment: input: 3.54 , 525.43, 72.50                                                                                                   Outout: ***$3.54,  **$525.43,  ***$72.50,

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**  With the sample inputs and expected output given in the comment, my previous answer was not correct.

Given each of those inputs, this update should produce the expected output:

```
String value = "$" + String.format("%.2f", check);
System.out.println(value);
String check_fmt = ("*********" + value).substring(value.length());
System.out.println(check_fmt);
```

Note: borrowed ingenuity from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4051991/1248974)

old answer: <s>Not sure if it could be done with `printf()`, but [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) works,</s>

```
String result = String.format("%6.2f", check); // 6 spaces width, 2 spaces precision, 'f' converts the double
System.out.println(result.replace(" ", "*"));
```

Note: used 6 spaces width = 3 spaces for whole dollar + 2 spaces for cents + 1 space for decimal