# Translate Hexadecimal transformation from Oracle SQL into Java code

Tags: java, hex

In searching for an answer, I used the solution provided in the following link : [How to format a Java string with leading zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051887/how-to-format-a-java-string-with-leading-zero)

I have the following code that needs to be translated into java:

```
TRIM(TO_CHAR(123,'000X'))
```

From what I can tell, it translates the number into hexa and adds some leading zeros.

However, if I give a big value, I get `#####` as answer, e.g. for the following code:

```
TRIM(TO_CHAR(999999,'000X'))
```

In Java, my current solution is the following:

```
String numberAsHex = Integer.toHexString(123);
System.out.println(("0000" + numberAsHex).substring(numberAsHex.length()));
```

It works fine for small numbers, but for big ones, like `999999` it outputs `423f`. So it does the transformation, resulting the value `f423f` and then it cuts a part off. So I am nowhere near the value from Oracle

Any suggestion as to how to do this? Or why are `#####` displayed in the Oracle case?

Comment: Look at `SimpleNumberFormat` class.

Comment: `TO_CHAR` outputs '#' characters when the format string is not large enough to accommodate the formatted output. `TO_CHAR(999999,'000X')` has to output five hex digits (F423F), but the format string only allows room for four characters. To indicate this condition `TO_CHAR` outputs four '#' characters instead of throwing an exception and abnormally terminating the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Integer.toHexString` I would recommend using [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) because of its greater flexibility.

```
int number = ...;
String numberAsHex = String.format("%06x", number);
```

The `06` means you get 6 digits with leading zeros, `x` means you get lowercase hexadecimal.

Examples:

- for `number = 123` you get `numberAsHex = "00007b"`
- for `number = 999999`you get `numberAsHex = "0f423f"`